# How do I start printing from the middle of a string in ASM?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I have an assignment that requires me to print out characters starting from a certain position in a string (ranging anywhere within the string) and I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. This is the code that I have tried so far

```
SYS_EXIT equ 1
SYS_READ equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1

segment .bss
    curLen resb 1

section .text
    global main

main:
    mov ecx,2
    mov [curLen],ecx     ; Store starting position

    mov edx,10    ; Only print out 10 characters
    mov ecx,txt    ; Load string address into register
    add ecx,curLen    ; Add starting position to string address
    mov ebx,STDOUT ;
    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    int 0x80
    jmp exit

exit:
    mov eax,SYS_EXIT
    int 0x80

section .data
    txt db 'This a string', 0x0
```

Any idea what could be going wrong? Ideally the above code would print out "`is is a st`", which starts two characters into the string and prints out the following 10.

Thanks!

Comment: `add ecx,curLen` should be `add ecx,[curLen]`.

Comment: Agree with Jester, and I'd also address the issue that _curLen_ is defined as 1 byte (`curLen resb 1`) and we move a 32 bit register to it with `mov [curLen],ecx`

Comment: @Jester you should have made your comment an answer!! Also @Michael Petch I changed `resb` to `resd` and it seems to have solved the issue. Thanks both of you!

Comment: I'd also highly recommend a debugger like _gdb_ or even the graphical interface to _gdb_ like _ddd_ (if you are new to _gdb_) . If you step through the code and watch the registers one would have noticed that after `add ecx,curLen` the register `ecx` contained an incorrect value. If you use _gdb_ and/or _ddd_ I'd recommend assembling with dwarf debug info with something like `nasm -f elf -F dwarf -g filename.asm`